# Create/Display a new Div each time text is submitted by a user

Tags: javascript

I want to display the content of a text field in a new div when it is submitted, every time the submit button under the text field is clicked I'd like a new div created.

For example, Person A enters 'hello' and hits submit, 'hello' is now displayed elsewhere on the page.

Person B shows up and types 'hello again' and hits submit, 'hello again' is also displayed in the next div after the first 'hello', etc.

Is this functionality even possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, I've found the solution to creating new divs on a button click and I've found the solution to displaying text from a form, I just have no idea how the two could be combined.

Comment: Are you talking about creating a complete chat kind of application? In that case you have to do server side programming and handling databases.

Comment: No, I want users to be able to add simple lines of text to a webpage that everybody can see, they won't necessarily saying hello to each other.

Comment: I think this is beyond me.  Thank you all for the help, its appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've created an example of what you want using jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/sVgxa/

HTML:

```
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<button id="submit">Enter</button>
<div id="newDivs"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
   var text = $('#input').val();
   $('#newDivs').append('<div>' + text + '</div>');
});
```

As trims said, if you want something that shows up between different users you will need something more complicated using Ajax.

Comment: So in this solution, only the person who has entered the text will be able to see the updated content on the page?
 
Thank you very much for this, it looks about what I want.

Comment: Yes, since this is purely client side code there isn't any connection to the server therefore no way of passing data to other users. Implementing that is much more complicated code than what I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use jQuery then -

HTML -

```
<input id="text-box" value="" />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<div id="message-wrapper"></div>
```

JavaScript -

```
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            $("#submit").click(
                    function() {
                        $("<div>" + $("#text-box").val() + "</div>").appendTo(
                                "#message-wrapper");
                    })
        });
```

Comment: I was also thinking along these lines but the question talks about multiple people adding messages which implies that there will need to be some communication with the server and need some form of database.

Comment: he got his answer, I think he was just fiddling with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe look like simple Ajax Web Chat application. Using just javascript will be not enough to get what you want. You could check this example:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application/
Or google for how to create Ajax Chat application. There is a lot of good examples of how to create such app using different programming languages.

Comment: If this is the solution then I'm willing to surrender right now lol.  Thank you though, you've given me a pointer to google.