# Display user input to a different Div on button click

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Currently on button click, I'm able to display the user input from inside the textbox, but it's displayed inside the same Div every time.

Textbox and the button (HTML file)-

```
<input type="text" name="inputText"><br>

<tr>
        <input type="button" value="ADD" ng-click="$ctrl.addtext()">
</tr>

<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

JS function-

```
ctrl.addtext = function () {
    var div = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
    div.innerHTML += newtext+"\n";
}
```

How can I get the user input in a different Div and a newline every time?

EDIT: A similar question has been asked for JQuery and it's JS is-

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var text = $('#input').val();
    $('#newDivs').append('<div>' + text + '</div>');
});
```

How can I do that append in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work using this in the JS function-

```
div.innerHTML += "<div>"+newtext+"</div>\n";
```

Instead of-

```
div.innerHTML += newtext+"\n";
```

Reference (solved for Jquery)-

[Create/Display a new Div each time text is submitted by a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302922/create-display-a-new-div-each-time-text-is-submitted-by-a-user)